# Cloud Datastore - Make Use of Small Operations

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, query-optimization

in my Google Cloud Datastore, using App Engine, I have approximately 1000 entities of type `A`.

I need to pre-load the whole list of entities, constantly updating, every time a user logs in. I can't do it static.

Taking advantage of Google Cloud Datastore pricing model (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing) I changed the query code from:

```
a_entities = A.query().fetch()
```

to:

```
a_keys = A.query().fetch(keys_only=True)
a_entities = ndb.get_multi(a_keys)
```

So that I remain in the daily free quota, since I move much of the read operations to the type "Datastore Small Operations", which are free and unlimited, as I read.

Is this a sound solution? Would it be able to sustain a certain traffic in case it increases much? Would it impact other resources?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `keys_only` query is free (just 1 operation).  But the next line, where you `get_multi` the actual entities is not free.  You have not discovered a loophole to remain within the free quota.

Comment: Ok thanks, by testing around, I found that this tends to perform way better on the quota than the first line. Is it because of memcache?

Comment: @FedericoCapello if the values were in memcache you would benefit from this approach from a cost standpoint (assuming using shared memcache).  However from a performance standpoint you are incurring 2 roundtrips.  In high volume scenarios you would also want to watch out for hot key problems